# Mapping nested objects using streams to pair all possible combinations in a List

Tags: java, list, stream, java-stream, java-11

Let's say I've a nested object that contains a distinct pair of String-Integer objects (let's call each such pair as `endpoint`). There's a List called `pair` which contains exactly 2 `endpoint` objects. And another List called `pairs` that can contain any number of (say `n`) `pair` entries and I need to collect every unique pair of Strings along with their corresponding Integer values in a new object.

Consider the following classes for existing object:

```
    public class Endpoint {
        private String key;
        private Integer number;

        public Endpoint(String key, Integer number) {
            this.key = key;
            this.number = number;
        }

        // Getters, Setters and toString()
    }

    public class Pair {
        // It will have exactly 2 entries
        List<Endpoint> pair;

        public Pair(List<Endpoint> pair) {
            this.pair = pair;
        }

        // Getters, Setters and toString()
    }
```

Consider the following object (before transformation), where `pairs` is a `List<Pair>`. The entries in `pairs` can be in any order:

```
pairs: [
        pair: [{"p1",1000},{"p2",2000}],
        pair: [{"p1",3000},{"p3",4000}],
        pair: [{"p2",5000},{"p3",6000}],
        pair: [{"p1",2000},{"p2",3000}],
        pair: [{"p1",2001},{"p2",3001}],
        pair: [{"p1",4000},{"p3",5000}],
        pair: [{"p1",4001},{"p3",5001}],
        pair: [{"p2",6000},{"p3",7000}],
        pair: [{"p2",6001},{"p3",7001}]

]
```

Consider the following classes to populate the result:

```
    public class CustomEndpoint {
        private String key;
        // `numbers` can have any number of entries
        private List<Integer> numbers;

        public CustomEndpoint(String key, List<Integer> numbers) {
            this.key = key;
            this.numbers = numbers;
        }

        // Getters, Setters and toString()
    }

    public class CustomPair {
        // It will have exactly 2 entries
        List<CustomEndpoint> pair;

        public CustomPair(List<CustomEndpoint> pair) {
            this.pair = pair;
        }

        // Getters, Setters and toString()
    }
```

I need to collect it as follows:

```
custom-pairs: [
    custom-pair: {[{"p1", [1000,2000,2001]}, {"p2", [2000,3000,3001]}]},
    custom-pair: {[{"p1", [3000,4000,4001]}, {"p3", [4000,5000,5001]}]},
    custom-pair: {[{"p2", [5000,6000,6001]}, {"p3", [6000,7000,7001]}]}
]
```

where `custom-pairs` is a `List<CustomPair>`. The order of entries in the `numbers` List must be maintained as it were for the input `pair`. e.g Since `1000` in p1 was paired with `2000` in p2, if `1000` is the first entry in `numbers` List for p1 then `2000` must also be the first entry in `numbers` List for p2, for the combination where p1 and p2 are paired together.

How can I do this using Streams in Java?

Comment: what is criteria of collect here?

Comment: The criteria is to collect pairs based on the String. eg: All Integers for the pair p1 and p2 are collected in a list and combined in one object. Similarly, all Integers for the pair p1 and p3 are combined in another object and same goes for p2 and p3 pair.

Comment: I don't understand how you want the resulting data to be organized. What do the curly brackets and square brackets represent?

Comment: (I do get the impression it'd be easier with a loop instead.)

Comment: Agree with @Shawn the structure of your objects is not clear. What **type** would you expect as a result in Java ? To begin with, please provide the definition of the `Pair` class and your code-attempt to approach this problem (doesn't matter with streams or loops).

Comment: I've updated the class structures above!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the clarifications you've given about the classes and their structure I've updated my answer.

Basically, you could group the `Pair` elements in your list `pairs` by the keys of the two contained endpoints. To make the code more readable, I've added a method in your `Pair` class (`getPairKeys`) which returns the two endpoint's keys chained together, but you can avoid it by simply chaining the keys right in the stream if you prefer.

After grouping the `Pair` elements by their keys, you'll get a `Map` where each chained key maps to the n `Pair` instances with the same keys. At this point, you could stream the `Map`s entries, map each entry to a `CustomPair`, sort them by the first number of the first `CustomEndpoint` and ultimately collect the instances.

To make my solution work, I've assumed that the implementation of `equals` (and so also of `hashCode`) is present in both `Pair` and `Endpoint`. Also, as I said before, I've added a `getPairKeys` method within your `Pair` class to get a `String` mapping each `Pair` and a `getFirstPairInitialNumber` method in the `CustomPair` class to establish a sorting order among `CustomPair`. All the code I've just mentioned can be consulted in the link below. I preferred not to post it here to avoid a wall of text and focusing only the actual solution.

```
List<CustomPair> listRes = pairs.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Pair::getPairKeys))  //Grouping the Pairs by the keys of the two EndPoints (key1:key2)
        .entrySet().stream()    //Streaming the entries of the map
        .map(entry -> {
            String key1 = null, key2 = null;

            //Lists for the values of the CustomEndpoint
            List<Integer> listValues1 = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Integer> listValues2 = new ArrayList<>();

            //Retrieving the keys and adding each pair's number to the respective lists
            for (Pair p : entry.getValue()) {
                key1 = p.getPair().get(0).getKey();
                key2 = p.getPair().get(1).getKey();

                listValues1.add(p.getPair().get(0).getNumber());
                listValues2.add(p.getPair().get(1).getNumber());
            }

            //Returning the new CustomPair in place of the two grouped by Pair
            return new CustomPair(new ArrayList<>(List.of(
                    new CustomEndpoint(key1, listValues1),
                    new CustomEndpoint(key2, listValues2))));
        })
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(CustomPair::getFirstPairInitialNumber))    //Ordering the CustomPair by the beginning of their endpoint range
        .collect(Collectors.toList());  //Collecting the CustomPair
```

Here is an updated link to test the code

https://ideone.com/G3XlRS

##### Output

[image]

Comment: This will only work if the `pair` entries in the `pairs` List are arranged appropriately. If the `pair` entries are jumbled, it won't work. We must keep track of the key to arrange it properly.

Comment: @Aman yeah I've assumed they were ordered because in your example the data were arranged exactly like that

Comment: True, but that's not always guaranteed, I've clarified that aspect in the question now. Is there a way to do it, when they're not ordered?

Comment: yes, but I need to know the ordering criteria though

Comment: The input list has no ordering, but while generating the output structure, all pair of keys must be grouped together. For Example: In the above example, we have 3 different keys i.e p1, p2 and p3. So, we need to group for all possible pairs of p1, p2 and p3 i.e (p1,p2), (p1, p3) and (p2,p3). Similarly if we had four keys, we would have got 6 pairs (all 4C2 combinations) in the output. Does that help?

Comment: That's correct!

Comment: Were you able to come up with an approach to collect all combinations in the given manner, using streams?

Comment: @Aman yes, check the output I've posted. You could also execute my code at the link I've provided in my answer. https://ideone.com/G3XlRS

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I noticed another aspect, regarding which I could've been more explicit earlier. However I did mention that the number of entries in `numbers` List can be any number, which essentially means that there's no guarantee that in the input List, there will be only 2 entries for a given pair of keys e.g p1 and p2 can have 4 entries as well, just that if p1 and p2 has 4 entries then all other combinations will also have exactly 4 entries. And the number of entries can be queried explicitly beforehand in constant time, if required.

Comment: @Aman ok, could you provide an example of how to build a CustomPair with 4 Pairs? Maybe edit your question

Comment: `CustomPair` can only have 2 pairs, as the name suggests. But the `pairs` List, which is provided as input can have more than 2 entries for any given pair of keys, I'll update the input accordingly.

Comment: @Aman so, you're saying that a `Pair` can appear multiple times of two (2,4,6,8,....), right?

Comment: It can appear any number of times (up to 16) 1,2,3,4,5,6,...16. I've updated the input for the case when they are repeated 3 times. The exact number of times for which they will be repeated can be queried beforehand in constant time, if that helps.

Comment: @Aman I've updated my answer and the link to test the code above https://ideone.com/G3XlRS

Comment: Thanks a lot, the new code works for all scenarios :)